# Is this the correct usage of commas in Alice in Wonderland?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas

Reading *Alice in Wonderland*, I noticed a strange use of commas:

> The only things in the kitchen that did not sneeze**,** were the cook**,** and a large cat which was sitting on the hearth and grinning from ear to ear.

I would have expected no commas:

> The only things in the kitchen that did not sneeze were the cook and a large cat which was sitting on the hearth and grinning from ear to ear.

Why is this, and is it correct?

Comment: In a world where it's verdict first, then trial, Carroll can do as he pleases, and we can't. Every element the writer chose was deliberate. Was there actually a "large cat ... grinning from ear to ear"?

Comment: There is no "correct" for commas. You put them in when you hear them. And since it's been almost 200 years since they were written, it's hard to tell what they might have sounded like.

Comment: Lewis Carroll could write any way he cared.

Comment: I would have expected no commas. *The only things in the kitchen that did not sneeze* is the subject, which should not be separated from its verb in this way. However, the "pause comma" exists (a lot of people don't like it) which is used by some writers to inform the reader how the sentence should be read. I suggest you don't use this comma. The comma after "cook" is similar - it makes "... and a large cat..." appear to be an intriguing addition. The cat will play a part in the story...

Comment: Lewis Carroll used more commas than is currently common.  Later in the same story he has "... when it grunted again, so violently, that she looked down into its face in some alarm."